# Understanding Variable of Integration

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, change-of-variable

I am currently trying to get a deeper understanding of multivariable calculus and I am finding my one stumbling block to be the variable of integration. In single variable calculus, I have always considered the variable of integration (in antiderivatives) as the "what do I have to differentiate the answer with respect to in order to get the integrand." For instance, in the following:

$$\int 2x dx=x^2$$

I have always interpreted the *dx* as meaning I have to differentiate my answer ($x^2$) with respect to *x* in order to get my integrand ($2x$). In other words, I have to take $\frac{d}{dx}$ of $x^2$ to get $2x$.

I am struggling to understand a certain concept though: multiplication of variables of integration. Say, for instance, that I have the following:

$$\int (x -6)^2 dx$$

If I define $u = x - 6$, I can write the following equivalent integral

$$\int u^2 \frac{du}{dx}dx$$

It seems to me that now there are "multiple" variables of integration. Am I looking for an answer that I have to differentiate with respect to $u$ or $x$ in order to get the integrand? This can be simplified to:

$$\int u^2 du$$

Now, it is clear that I am looking for a function that I have to differentiate with respect to $u$ in order to get my integrand. However, I don't understand why the variables of integration ($dx$) can just cancel. My understanding is that they must mean more than "what do I have to differentiate my answer...." In the case of definite integrals, it is relatively clear (I can imagine them as small changes along a certain axis). But, with indefinite integrals, I cannot think of what they represent. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can cancel out the $dx$'s so you have $\int u^2 \ du$. Integrate with respect to $u$, and once you have your final answer substitute the expression with the $x$ back in. The reason you're allowed to cancel out the $dx$'s is because $\int \frac{dg(x)}{dx}f(g(x)) dx = F(g(x)) + C$ from the chain rule ($F$ is an antiderivative of $f$). 

So you can conveniently let "$u=g(x)$" so the equality reads, more naturally, $\int f(u) \ du = F(u) + C$. This is, essentially, what a change of variables boils down to. You're reversing the chain rule.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why you multiplied your integrand $u^2 dx$ by $\frac{du}{dx}$... Did you know that $\frac{du}{dx}$ equaled to 1 in this case?  Or is there another reason? For example if you were to do something similar to your first integral would you write $\int 2x dx$ with $u=2x$ as $\int u \frac{du}{dx} dx$ or would you write it as $\int u \cdot \frac{1}{2} \frac{du}{dx} dx$?... Just asking because I'm trying to get clarity on the question.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I wrote the $\frac{du}{dx}$ out to emphasize what I am asking: what does the variable of integration mean? Why can it be cancelled? In that specific problem, it could be replaced with $1$, but I am wondering about a more general case.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, does that mean that the cancelling is more of a convenient notation trick than "actual math"?

Comment: @dts Exactly. You can ascribe $dx$, $dy$, $dz$ a formal definition in terms of differential forms or non-standard analysis, but I don't really think that's necessary in the context of basic calculus. The relevant theorems pertaining to substitution simply state that when $f$ is continuous and $g$ is continuously differentiable, $$\int g'(x)f(g(x)) dx = F(g(x)) + C$$ and $$\int_a^b g'(x)f(g(x)) dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u) du$$ There's nothing special about the variable $u$. Actually, you can even replace it with $x$ and the equality remains correct. It is simply a matter of notation.

Comment: Also writing $\int_a^x f(y)dy$ instead of $\int f(x)dx$ is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

What you are talking about is a technique called *integration by substitution* it is a *techique* to integrate functions involving chain rule in their derivative.In fact it comes to help the power rule to find the anti-derivative, however, the power rule to find the anti-derivative becomes useless if the derivation contains applying the chain rule, that is, in order to apply the *power rule* you have to guarantee that the integration will stop at applying the power rule so we integrate with respect to *the derivative of the inner function*(the function we were going to apply the chain rule at i.e *u* in your example.